# Prove that exist some base of V such that does not have any vector from subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ is some m-dimensional subspace of n-dimensional space $V$, where $m<n$. Prove that exist some base of $V$ such that does not have any vector from subspace $W$

Can someone help me, I know that trivial subspace have vector that does not belong in base of some space, but what do you think?

Comment: I'm really glad you accepted my answer, but you did it no more than 1 minute after I posted it. Did you take the time to verify that the proof works? People on the internet are not perfect, and some answer could contains mistakes, or even be plain wrong

Comment: I think that is ok because if you have sum of some vector from subspace and other vector, that does not mean that it belong in that subspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(w_1,\ldots,w_m)$ be a base of $W$

Since $m<n$, you can find a non empty list of vectors $(v_1,\ldots,v_{n-m})$ such that $(w_1,\ldots,w_m,v_1,\ldots,v_{n-m})$ is a base of $V$ and no $v_i$ is in $W$

Now, verify that $(w_1+v_1,\ldots,w_i+v_1,\ldots,w_m+v_1,v_1,\ldots,v_{n-m})$ is also a base of $V$, and that none of the vector of this base belongs to $W$

For a more geometrical insight, consider a plan $P$ in the usual space $\mathbb R^3$. If you plan is spanned by $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$, the space can be spanned by $\{(1,0,1),(0,1,1),(0,0,1)\}$, and no vector of this basis belongs to $P$

Comment: I think that you need put n-m, not m-n

Comment: Good catch, editing that. It also answer my comment on the main post. You did read this through and catch a mistake on my side.